# Display data.frame data using grid.arrange

Tags: r

I'm nearing the end of my program where I need to spit out pretty graphs and some data.
I think I've turned most of my google search links purple by now trying to figure this out, though I'm sure I'm doing something silly.

Example code is below. I have three graphs that I want to display along with a dataframe from values, and then use the grid.arrange function to order them nicely.

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=sin)
g2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=tan)
g3 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=cos)
g4 <- grid.table(data.frame(x <- 1:10, y<-2:11, z<-3:12))

grid.arrange(g1,g2,g3,g4, nrow=2)
```

Of course this doesn't work. 
I'm not sure if there is something to adjust within grid.table to move it to the bottom right, or if I should be using some other function that works within grid.table.
Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `tableGrob` instead of `grid.table` [also you forgot about library(gridExtra)]

Comment: I must be using tableGrob incorrectly. When I do `tableGrob((data.frame(x <- 1:10, y<-2:11, z<-3:12))` for example, R, spits out many lines of gibberish: `NULL, 1, 0.5, 0.5, center, 0, FALSE, row-label-1, black, 0.8, italic, 3, 2, 0.5, 0.5, center, 0, FALSE, row-label-2, black, 0.8, italic, 3, 3, 0.5, 0.5, center, 0, FALSE, row-label-3, black, 0.8, italic, 3, 4, 0.5, 0.5, center, 0, FALSE, row-labe` etc..

Comment: Ah sorry I figured it out :) g4 <- tableGrob... etc. Thanks. I was overthinking it.

Comment: @user3564760, please post your solution as an answer and accept it so that others can see that the question has been resolved. Thanks.

Comment: note: you should really avoid the `<-` assignment inside `data.frame`; it's probably not doing (only) what you think it's doing. Use `=` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by user20650 in comments above:

> Use tableGrob instead of grid.table [also you forgot about library(gridExtra)] –  user20650